# Two-dimensional unipotent algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

How to prove that two-dimensional unipotent algebraic group over the field of characteristic 0 is commutative?

Comment: How is the multiplication of upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Well, this group is obviously commutative.

Comment: Every closed unipotent group is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of the upper triangular matrices with 1's on the diagonals. See Armand Borel's book for instance.